# Looking for CircuitPython module equivalent to usb_cdc for Feather M4 Express

Tags: javascript, serial-port, usb, microcontroller, adafruit-circuitpython

I've assembled this 8x8 button grid using the Feather M4 Express microcontroller:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1929?gclid=CjwKCAjwgOGCBhAlEiwA7FUXkj1TknNJexUvCwRb1t8fUJwJhQvC8wREmAs5AojE4wSHWsoNKLWkcRoCFUIQAvD_BwE

I want to be able to connect the grid to a website with USB such that the website responds to buttons being pressed on the grid and the grid responds to activity on the website. I was hoping to do this with a USB serial connection. On the web-dev side, I was planning on using the Web Serial API:

https://web.dev/serial/

On the microcontroller side, I am stuck on finding a CircuitPython module suitable for sending messages over a USB serial port. Ideally, I would like to use the usb_cdc module, but it is not supported on the Feather M4 Express

https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shared-bindings/usb_cdc/index.html

Is there a suitable module supported by the Feather M4 Express for sending data over USB serial? Are there any other solutions for getting a website and a Feather M4 Express microcontroller to talk to each other over USB? Any tips or advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the place to take survey to see if others know of a library.  Explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the proper way to write to serial with the Feather M4 Express is with the busio module.

https://learn.adafruit.com/circuit-playground-express-serial-communications/circuitpython

Hope it's helpful for others!

Answer (score 0):

BTW `usb_cdc` **is** currently supported on the Feather M4 Express.